# How to make this T-flip-flop circuit

Tags: circuit-design, relay, flipflop, latch, latching

I am trying to make a T-flip-flop circuit with a relay, which would:

- **toggle** on a button press (12 V) [default state: off]
- allow **control from** an external **micro-controller** (optocouplers)
- allow switching between *standalone* button control and external control [if possible by signal rather than an SPDT switch]
- allow the **button to be read** by the micro-controller
- have very low-power consumption
- bonus: after switching `external->standalone`, the status is remembered
- bonus: simple, cheap, circuit with a n-MOSFET for driving the relay, embeddable many times on a PCB

However, I am having trouble with designing a real-life working circuit.

---

[The first version](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgosgCgAXEPKsQqltqEAWgm5gAsGBNhHY0GAYSx5CPGG0gCUKBMwyyEagUzi0ASj0I7ic7qZAX2IASxRd20BLQDuRk3KpXXXK%20AE6dG5ecmh4lp60AE664JxgAXHWYPDwPiwYniBhUD4JOqwZcoW5bmCZSdn4lUHZeOElKPVV4XQx5cXxFSi2XCmped29HSC4gbQAZtk92b1N4T1U4tlQ0Cg%208y11CzO1KjqL0wcY9rVUmPb72Se5AMbgFWMPctjYWWAAptyt0LjSPQDIKQwCDsBholwLlxXu8Bm5NqpQs1RKcNsiEPYRijSs9RhjofizqM3gTUWVHiSsYTaABzUk8Zh4sm4w75WbsdJbc69ImHc43Xm9AQLHm0ADONhFLESfPAIHoUQArh8Nr0LJtvPDhpxNiU9tV1WrIvDqo1tRyYodDRxkmkACZbRoG0IgO0fCYAQ0VABt6LRygtmsZRoRwsGWKtTk48FJCGCY4RVMQEKxVpAkP1UmnLntmiDLnnOHQgA) I worked with didn't have the button connected to 12 V on one side, as it switched the two sides of the flip-flop.

My [modified second version](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEAOAnLAzKgbBsqB2AJiMgwwBYQFJrraEBTAWjDACgwDlxIiqMkKmyEhBVIuCjRJRGZGwUCqDLiLIiWMERYFpkJGHjx9s2jEhgkFg1HYAnEIWwgKcJwRfkXDbHHYAJk4UVG60qCFiqiCSAYwAZgCGAK4ANgAuDsGhitmu7rRGxuzpKBiSFDhlFbkQEMxyWAgIqAhgFGDYqMgEGEzMeswU0KijoxQIFNg0FIKG7nFJaZkAztXUfuuVPlLp9smMJesIm8jl1KiStKyuI2OjBJ0hcDw28JOQEa3qqEIYBAR5rRFikMuw3HpsMRqNoQNhkDw2pIOKUoRV3IpaGEoCAbsN7r9NKQkWAeMw3nBWtoIgjsFZKPgeMgFglQZlHGj8rRei5sYVjP54h4XNMXEZ%20HCTmJZNIiOwAMpwhGSkVuFU4iBJVIrRg4uWOZzqw3Ecy8eDsADGeRakgiVExGpYPHx9wmdLtjwgNg4jjQLhOtD9riqvn8EODqqxzLhao4AHdeBKTcKQMnIOwE8bSHk0xmc9nObmE5ybXDoUXE-boeKqBW7THwpEKzWoi5Dd47JnPK28h30wmgxRo0G%203n6x2R9F%20w2xMh7WrR8WF9FJz486WHaXFxdJB2Hdv4TxRSnj9OHee1aXp8hOq5cg6plRr7eN5fLp2UEO71R64%20P3PEXfesrzHSJS1-XJryqANjk2adf3cQ0%20THbtsRbZCE3Q9wWz6K48xbB0sPMUDQncHkuQ-DdoXPaEoN5Ycqm2D9N3fB9ILzNj5yxW9r3OJjOSYs9oX46EkTsABzMtJGTQspwk1N4WoJtFJg4iAFkFMRWFPERdQ9WgBAsh0mFpLnEyNXNAAlVMzLE5kGFhU1LxxcwDKyfi1SYq8zXTAAZCMd1caNvM1RJtV1ax2EkkSKiqQ8XPYayt2iBBuz7HFYyuFy3I5UTWNEyJ%20X8IA) does work in theory in the simulator, however, it does not work in reality, which, I suppose is the result of non-ideal and complex workings of transistors.

---

I am also considering usage of IC flip-flops, however, I also had trouble designing something which would fulfill all the points.

---

*For referring to the components:*

[image: circuit design]

Note: this is a WIP drawing, the button and the relay will not be located on the PCB, etc...

Comment: Where is the problem with D flip-flop like 7474 connected with negative feedback (Q_neg to D input)? It leads to nice one chip solution + NPN/NMOS for driving relay. Do not forget on RC button debouncing on Clk input for adding reliability.

Comment: There is 2 flip-flops in 7474. Use the remaining other for "debouncing switch". Use CMOS parts.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEY73Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[Falstad's Relay T flop, my version.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgrCAMB0lwTBAjADmvA7CgnEs%20UA2JAFgzHnEnCvAFMBaJJAKCSxBMJJE0rELU%20IQiCRRo4hjDiyihQXkLYwkFOpI8ZyWbImRK8ajMozIESCwBKIAMwoet26JJw7zqJ9c1jEsCwB3O0IUO0geLkdwqEDg0OF7HmFLIOd4%20B4wbEMMmKCBIXVwQTCtFgBnXiL4aurvanEAFwAnAFc6Fma7B3dRRLsjTyQ4Ng4a%20KK0qtDRU0kQaVhzfFtmXEJ4GqUSC1gdXWNYQ0ODfXM8uN4BTiRZ65Sb2YxKElur0QfXu5dud4uvuwUR68Z4xADmnF%20tmikV6ngeU1sg36SOMLAAHldxJt4rheKtOGJRI0APZgsEAGw6QXGgJeb1sQIRPVR3SSoM%20v0QP3ZhliBWm4GygoeWRymWFtMsEJISN43gBGV8D1pjMMk0Gli6sO5kKS9U4GEstxeXIVcqVvBAABM6AAzACGrQpjQYVOtYnh%20lYQA)